# Automate my sql query for every week

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have some codes in SQL developer in which we are pulling data from oracle server and then we are doing too many updation and calculation using sub-queries. In some sub-queries we used join also. Finally we have a single block of codes with multiple sub-queries inside it. Now we need to run this code every month to update data for our new created table, so we want to automated this process and i don't know how to automate these codes in SQL developer

Comment: This doesn't seem to be anything to do with SQL Developer, or really with the details of what you are doing (calculations, subqueries, joins). I think you're really trying to find out [how to schedule jobs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse.htm).

Comment: I want to write Stored procedure for these codes and then we can schedules these procedures for auto refresh. So can you help me to write stored procedure for this query with multiple sub query

Comment: Without knowing anything about the query or what you will do with the results of that query? No. Even with that information it would be too broad a question. [Start here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS008).